# Locating an element in any iframe using Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm using Playwright to do some end to end automation on a web application composed of multiple nested iframes. For now, I decompose the multiple iframes using `frameLocator` and then I try to locate an element in the desired iframe:

```js
const firstFrame = await page.frameLocator("#firstIframe");
const secondFrame = await firstFrame.frameLocator("#secondIframe");
const element = await secondFrame.locator("input").fill("Some text")
```

Is there a way to locate an element in any iframe so I don't need to decompose all the nested iframes?

Comment: No, there is no way to accomplish that out-of-the-box

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this method in C#, you can transfer this in Javascript:

```
public async Task<IElementHandle> FindElement(string selector)
{
    IElementHandle element = null;

    var Pages = _context.Pages.ToArray();

    foreach (var w in Pages)
    {
        //============================================================
        element = await w.QuerySelectorAsync(selector);
        if (element != null)
        {
            return element;
        }

        //============================================================
        var iframes = w.Frames.ToList();
        var index = 0;

        for (; index < iframes.Count; index++)
        {
            var frame = iframes[index];

            
            element = await frame.QuerySelectorAsync(selector);
            if (element is not null)
            {
                return element;
            }

            var children = frame.ChildFrames;

            if (children.Count > 0 && iframes.Any(x => children.Any(y => y.Equals(x))) == false)
            {
                iframes.InsertRange(index + 1, children);
                index--;
            }
        }
    }

    return element;
}
```

First, it tries to find the element in the current page, a folly attempt most of the times, but if it does, then it saved time, then if it doesn't find it it will search all the iframes in the page then searches for the element in each frame, while searching in each frame it will search for the children frames of the frames, adding them to a list and iterating from the child onwards, this way it will search for the element you need in any nested frame.

When I transitioned to Playwright from Selenium I half heartedly expected Playwright to already have this functionality implemented, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, quick and dirty:

```
async function querySelectorAllFrames( page, selector )
{
    let frames = [ page, ... page.frames() ];

    while ( frames.length > 0 )
    {
        let f = frames.shift();

        let found = await f.$( selector );

        if ( found != null )
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```